# Is this Construction of an Example of Embedding Correct?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

**Is this construction of an example of embedding correct?**

We want to construct an example for the embedding $S^1\times S^1\rightarrow S^3$.

We define $f:S^1\times S^1\rightarrow S^3$ by

$f(\theta, \phi)=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}cos\theta,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}sin\theta, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}cos\phi, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}sin\phi)$.

Obviously, $f$ is well-defined. We know $f$ is injective as it assigns to each point $(\theta, \phi)$ a unique point on $S^3$. The sine and cosine functions together cover the unit circle uniquely for each $\theta$ and $\phi$ in the domain $[0,2\pi]$. The only overlaps that occurs in $[0,2\pi]$ for each variable corresponds to the same point on $S^1$, the unit circle. $S^1\times S^1$ gives a torus. So, each point on the torus is uniquely defined by each $(\theta, \phi)$, and each $(\theta, \phi)$gives a unique point on $S^3$ due to the orthogonal nature of the sine and cosine functions for each dimension.

Since the components of $f$ are the sine and cosine functions, which are continuous, then $f$ is continuous. Also,  since $S^1$ is compact, then $S^1\times S^1$ is compact (the product of two compact set is compact). Also, $S^3$ is Hausdorff (since $\mathbb{R}^4$ is Hausdorff, and $S^3\subseteq \mathbb{R}^4$). Since $f$ is continuous and injective, and is the map between a compact space and a Hausdorff space, then it is a homeomorphism.

Lastly, the differential $D_pf$ at $p=(\theta, \phi)$ gives a matrix with a full rank (a rank of 2) for any $\theta$ and $\phi$ because the rows are linearly independent (as both the sine and cosine functions do not vanish simultaneously). By the inverse function theorem, $f$ is locally injective. Hence, $f$ is an immersion.

Since f is a homeomorphism and an immersion, then f is an embedding.

Comment: Yes and I like this embedding; it is a clever way to avoid using the "usual" embedding of the torus into $\Bbb R^3\subset\Bbb R^3\cup\{\infty\}=S^3$. But it's also "clear" that it is an embedding since it's basically just $S^1\times S^1\hookrightarrow\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R^2$ scaled by $1/\sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid the use of $\sin$ and $\cos$. Actually your definition simply says that
$$f((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2) .$$
This map is a continuous injection, hence a topological embedding.

$f$ is the restriction of the smooth map
$$F : \mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R^2 = \mathbb R^4 \to  \mathbb R^4, F((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2) .$$
Note that $F$ is essentially the identity (with a scaling factor).

Since $S^1 \times S^1$ is a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R^2$ and $S^3$ is a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^4$, we see that $f$ is smooth:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
S^1 \times S^1 @>{f}>> S^3 \\
@V{i}VV @VV{j}V \\
\mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R^2 @>>{F}> \mathbb R^4
\end{CD}

The maps $i, j$ are the inclusions. For the differentials we get the commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
T_{(a,b)}S^1 \times S^1 @>{D_{(a,b)}f}>> T_{f(a,b)}S^3 \\
@V{D_{(a,b)}i}VV @VV{D_{f(a,b)}j}V \\
T_{(a,b)}\mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R^2 @>>{D_{(a,b)}F}> T_{F(a,b)}\mathbb R^4
\end{CD}

Since $D_{(a,b)}i$ and $D_{(a,b)}F$ are injective, also $D_{(a,b)}f$ must be injective. This proves that $f$ is an immersion.

Comment: I like your solution. However, if you don’t mind, why should the use of sine and cosine be avoided.

Comment: @MrProf Using $\sin$ and $\cos$ makes things unnecessarily complicated. These functions parameterize $S^1$ in the form $(x,y) = (\cos t, \sin t)$ with $t \in [0,2\pi]$ and then map the parameter $t$ back to $(\cos t, \sin t)$. You can do that, but the parameterization is not unique since $\sin 0 = \sin 2\pi$ and $\cos 0 = \cos 2\pi$. You discussed it in your question. Certainly there is no benefit in this approach. Moreover, the boundary points $0, 2\pi  \in [0,2\pi]$ have to be treated separately to show that $f$ is smooth and an  immersion. The approach in my answer is much more transparent.

Comment: Oh I see. In trying to show that $f$ is continuous, is it okay to refer to its components $f$ in your solution as polynomial functions?

Comment: @MrProf Yes, it is correct!